# How do I stop running the program?

Tags: c++

I wrote my code, but I have an error. It says:

> ('break' statement not in loop or switch statement)

The thing is that I use loop in a program, but before that I check if the condition in incorrect I **have to print out "False" and stop the program**, without reading next symbols. How do I have to do that?
Here is my code:

```
if(l % 2 == 0) {
    cout << "False";
    break;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << '*';
}
```

Comment: Change `break` to `return 0;`?

Comment: Presumably you are in `main`. If you are in `main` you can just `return` a value to exit the function like any other function.

Comment: if you want to make this loop to work only if (l%2==0) if false use else statement around this loop also you can use return to end program break is used to end loops

Comment: @Lolkek2281337 Under what conditions do you want the loop to terminate? As it is now, there is no way that loop will end until it's done 5 iterations - or something like a power outage stops it. You need to enter something inside the loop for it to `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `break` inside a `for` or `while` loop, or a `switch` statement.

If this is your `main` function, the program will exit once the `main` function is done.

This can be made by using the `return` statement (with a value to return, `0` is the default return value if the program ran successfully)

```
if (l%2 == 0) {
    cout << "False";
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    cout << '*';
}
```

Comment: There is also [the `std::exit` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) for use when the code is deeper into the program. Note the many caveats documented for `std::exit` and make sure it really is the right solution for your task.

Comment: Minor objection: `call` ... it's not a function.

Answer (score 1):

First option: further code won't be executed.

```
if(l%2==0){
    cout<<"False";
    return 1; //this ends program here
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<'*';}
```

or second

```
if(l%2==0){
cout<<"False";
}
else{
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<'*';}
}
```

By using else further code after else will be executed but not this for loop (if this l%2==1 for will be executed instead)

Comment: `return 1; //this ends program here` should read `return 1; //this ends function here`. If the function is `main`, rock and roll. If not...

Comment: @user4581301 after the simplicity of the task, I assumed that at the moment the questioner does not yet know about the function, hence the end of the program as a comment! But ofc you are right!

Comment: @MerMonkey The question is indeed incomplete - so it's better to not let the answer give the illusion of having a better precision that the question had in the first place. I'm the first to sign on having been guilty a number of times...